# Constructor with Field from another class is undefined?

Tags: java, class, object

I'm tasked by a newbie Java tutorial to do the below

1. In the user class:

   1. Create a method called readBook(Book book)
   2. readBook should print, "`<User> read <title>`"
2. In the BookRunner

   1. For each book, create an author.
   2. Separately, create another user and call the readBook method on that user, passing in one of the created books

The below is my code:

```
public class Ex1_BookRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book firstBook = new Book("One Piece", "Oda-Sensei", 100, 123456);
        Book secondBook = new Book("Life of Megan Fox", "Micheal Bay", 200, 928765);
    }
}

public class User {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public String location;
    public Book title;

    public String toString() {
        String description1 = "Name:" + name + " Age:"+ age + " Location:" + location; 
        return description1;
    }

    public void readBook(Book book) {
        System.out.println(name + " read " + title.title);
    }
}

public class Book {
    public String title;
    public User author;
    public int numPages;
    public int isbn;

    public Book(String title, User author, int numPages, int isbn) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author =  author;
        this.numPages = numPages;
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String description = "Title:" + title + "Author"+ author.name + "Num. of pages" + numPages + "ISBN" + isbn; 
        return description;
    }   
}
```

I'm having problems even understanding what the question wants me to do. I've got the below questions

1. What does the question mean by getting me to print `<User> read <title>` with the readBook method? Did I interpret the question correctly with the way I set up the `readBook` method?

   What should be the correct code in the method?
2. I have problems getting the `author` created, as I get the error `The constructor Book(String, String, int, int) is undefined` and the Eclipse IDE wants me to change the constructor in `Book` from `(String, User, int, int)` to `(String, String, int, int)`. Experiments with User."Oda-Sensei", "Oda-Sensei".name, "Oda-Sensei.User" all give me the notice that the variable I'm introducing `cannot be resolved`.

Comment: `"Oda-Sensei".name` this is interesting. How should `"Oda-Sensei"` create a new instace of `User`? Since you should already know how to create new instances of a class, you shouldn't have difficulties to solve that problem.

Comment: If you're sure that `author` should be a `User`, then you will need to create a `User` to use as the second argument to `new Book(...)`.  And the only way to create a `User` with that name is `new User(...)`; it's best to make the "name" one of the arguments to the constructor.  That means you'll have to define a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the questioning, it sounds like authors are users. Your constructor calls in the main method are passing in strings, hence your error about the constructor. If authors are users, then you should change your calls from:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Book firstBook = new Book("One Piece", "Oda-Sensei", 100, 123456);
    Book secondBook = new Book("Life of Megan Fox", "Micheal Bay", 200, 928765);
}
```

to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    User odaSensei = new User();
    odaSensei.name = "Oda-Sensei";

    User michaelBay = new User();
    michaelBay.name = "Michael Bay";


    Book firstBook = new Book("One Piece", odaSensei, 100, 123456);
    Book secondBook = new Book("Life of Megan Fox", michaelBay, 200, 928765);
}
```

Be sure to set the other variables of the authors The other option is to change the type of authors to String, in which case the main method will not have the change.

I'd also recommend adding a constructor for Users, so that you can just initialize all of the variables from the new call.

The second part "Separately, create another user and call the readBook method on that user, passing in one of the created books"

Is telling you to create a brand new user, e.g. bob

```
User bobUser = new User();
bobUser.name="Bob";
```

and then take this new user and have him read one of the books:

```
bobUser.readBook(firstBook);
```

The goal is to get the read book to print out:

```
Bob read One Piece
```

To do this, you'll need to change the readBook method from:

```
public void readBook(Book book) {
    System.out.println(name + " read " + title.title);
}
```

to:

```
public void readBook(Book book) {
    System.out.println(name + " read " + book.title);
}
```

Comment: @Tom you're right, I misread it and thought user had a constructor. I'll update my answer to include the constructor